# How to remove a particular word from a text that satisfies a condition?

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, input, file-handling

I have a text file with lots of words. I'd like to remove words that contain repetitive letters(eg. zoos - contains 2 o's). What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Can you show the work you have done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) may work for you. Something like

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z])*([a-zA-Z])\\2([a-zA-Z])*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("zoo");
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Just add a loop to try every word in file and if `m.matches() == true` - delete it.

By the way, this won't work if you tYpE lIkE ThIs

Comment: Change [Oo] to [a-zA-Z]. He said repetitive chars not repetitive o.

Comment: No problem little guy. +1 for your effort :)

Comment: Wouldn't that match 'ab' and every other word with at leat two letters?

Comment: indeed, I'm a little hurried today... Well, stupid way would be trying all the letters (just 26 of them).

Comment: Actually, what you want is /([[:alpha:]])\1/ -- the [[:alpha:]] matches any alphabetic character, the (...) makes it a capture group, and \1 is a back-reference to that capture group, so it matches any repeated alphabetic character.

Comment: scottb, this looks fantastic. I completely forgot about capturing groups! As a more generic solution, I'd use ([a-z]|[A-Z])*([a-z]|[A-Z])\2([a-z]|[A-Z])*

Answer (score 0):

This is an example using a regex and the stream api:

```
package demo;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Demonstration
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> input = Arrays.asList( //
            new String[] {"a", "bb", "ccc", "ded", "ff", "ghi", "jkll"});

        // Prints [a, ded, ghi]
        System.out.println(removeWordsWithRepetitiveCharacters(input));
    }

    private static List<String> removeWordsWithRepetitiveCharacters(List<String> words)
    {
        return words.stream() //
            .filter(word -> !word.matches(".*(\\w)\\1+.*")) //
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```